# Column-level access control doesn't work in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I configured and turned on column-level access control, but it does not work. For a user with a Masked Reader role when choosing columns to which tags are added the data is selected unmasked

- data masking rule is Hash (SHA-256)
- columns type is String
- user does not have Fine-Grained Reader role
- access control on the taxonomy is enforced
- the taxonomy and tables exist in the same regional location

I did the same on testing environment - it worked

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are facing any error messages ?